# How does App connect to multiple components and multi-level components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have seen a code sample, inside of the file `App.js`, setting up `ComponentA`:

```
let connectedComponent = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ComponentA);


export default connectedComponent;
```

but what if `App` needs to use `ComponentB` as well -- how do you set it up?  What if `ComponentB` need to use `ComponentC` and also need to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

In react-redux `connect` is simply a higher order function that produces a new component, which has the redux state (mapStateToProps) and action creators (mapDispatchToProps) attached to the props object of the original `component` you passed to the function returned by `connect`. If you want more components to be *connected* to the redux store, you will have to pass them to the `connect` function.

See [Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) in the React documentation to understand how connect works.

It may also be beneficial to know that since `hooks` this is not the only option. You can use the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` functions exported from **react-redux** to use redux state and dispatch actions in your hook-enabled components.

Comment: how to set up `ComponentB` inside of `App.js`?

Comment: Is this a hypothetical, or do you know the content of `App.js`? I assume `ComponentB` is declared somewhere else? You have to connect `ComponentB` to the redux store using `connect`. You don't connect App to another component, you connect the redux store to a component.

Answer (score 0):

The clearest solution for this is to just put all the components into separate files and ***connect*** each one to the redux with their own ***mapStateToProps*** and ***mapDispatchToProps*** parameters. Then you can import the components to ***App.js*** and use them.

Comment: and to add another ComponentA to the page, you have to write those mapStateToProps, connect etc, one more time? The reducer has to be expanded, the action names need to be expanded, etc, etc? It is not just adding 1 line or 2 but have to deal with another 40-50 lines of code?

Comment: The App.js itself does not have to be connected to the redux. It is just a wrapper in this case which collects and shows the ComponentA, ComponentB, ... Then ComponentA has its own parts of the redux state which it needs for its functioning and ComponentB has its own parts of the redux state too defined in mapStateToProps. Redux is about connecting each component to the redux, then each component can use redux state directly using its props passed by _**connect**_ function.

Comment: (if componentA is a counter for the store property countA, and adding another componentA for countB)

Comment: Ok, in this case the best would be to connect the App to redux and in its mapStateToProps define mapping of countA and countB. Then in your componentA just make a new parameter named f.e. count and pass this count from App to componentA, you are going to have componentA in App twice, first time with count=countA and second time count=countB.

Answer (score 0):

> what if App needs to use ComponentB as well -- how do you set it up? What if ComponentB need to use ComponentC and also need to set it up?

If I get your question correct, componentB and componentC or/and componentN will be defined as child components of `App.js`.

Basically, `connect()` will link your component with the redux store so that whenever a change is detected in store each connected component will be notified with the change using `mapStateToProps`. Also, mutually exclusive components can be connected similarly with multiple `connect()`.